# UL LI is not aligned to left

Tags: html, css

I am learning html/css and have the following issue when aligning the "navigation menu" to the left. There's a small gap (see the pic below with a question mark)

can someone tell me how to remove the gap on the left side?

[image]

**Here is my html/css code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
#wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
#header {
    height: 200px;
    width: 800px;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
#navi {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #036;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
ul {
}
#content-area {
    height: 400px;
    width: 800px;
    background-color: #FFC;
}
#footer {
    height: 100px;
    width: 800px;
    background-color: #000;
}
h2 {
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
h3 {
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
}
p {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
}
li {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"><h2>This is the header</h2></div><!--header end--> 

        <div id="navi">
        <ul>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Twitter</li>
            <li>LinkdIn</li>
            <li>Google Plus</li>
        </ul>


        </div><!--navi end-->

    <div id="content-area"><p>Isn't saw evening shall open them had behold thing said evening i herb. Yielding kind second night image. Grass void green. Make Man given replenish brought. Spirit them seed fifth for living said his. Man abundantly.<br /><br />

Sixth yielding saying. Make female said they're night from fourth you'll make signs be. Our. Earth from. Replenish form living grass tree creepeth own. Had rule land from living, replenish appear the their days shall bearing waters moving seas living you, forth fourth.<br /><br />

Sixth whose stars i a. Creeping sea second above beast living signs created had first, face male dry our a his.</p></div>




<!--content area end-->

    <div id="footer"><h3>This is the Footer</h3></div><!--footer end-->

</div><!--wrapper end--> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I hope you have `normalize.css` included in your header.

Comment: In your browser (you use firefox or chrome yes?) right-click on the navigation bar and choose "inspect element"... now you can have a look at the styles on it and see which one is adding left-padding. (google for more info)

Comment: What's that?? can you please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `padding:0;` for your `ul` style.

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: @JannetMackenzie Then please choose this post as an answer

Answer (score 1):

The space is being applied from the default user agent style sheet.

You can remove it by explicitly setting padding, margin of `<ul>` to `0`.

It's a common practice to override it throughout the document like

```
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/ct52r67x/)

Answer (score 0):

[Please check this](http://jsfiddle.net/prashantptapase/9xdoumga/1/)

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add
 `ul{
padding:0;
}`

This will solve this issue. In general, you can use the following at the top of your CSS file:

```
    *{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

If you use this snippet at the top of your CSS, these problems won't occur and default padding etc. vary from browser-to-browser. So this will make it more consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you are using CSS **position** property? This is quite helpful. Also you can use these resources:

[CSS Box model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)

[CSS Padding](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp)

[CSS Margin](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp)
[CSS Positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

[more CSS Positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

You can use the 'Try it yourself' option to see it in real action. It's helpful and a good practice to set to **zero** all paddings and margins at the beginning at your code, like this:

`body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}`

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to avoid floating and use:

```
display: inline-block;
```

also you should give your ul id and apply the css settings to that #ulid >li this way you avoiding the rest of your li to get the menu rules.
Also I will recommend using some reset code as suggested in other answers so your CSS wont include the default browser CSS rules.

here are my modifications:

```
    #ulmenu > li {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    }

    #ulmenu{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"><h2>This is the header</h2></div><!--header end--> 

        <div id="navi">
        <ul id="ulmenu">
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Twitter</li>
            <li>LinkdIn</li>
            <li>Google Plus</li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue and all the paddings and margins were zero already, after much trawling through the inspector, I noticed there was text-indent on the li

```
li{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;  
 text-indent:0;
}
```

Fixed my issue.